# Which is most expensive query in django among these?

Tags: django

I have 5 models which needs to be populated using a key from 6th model:

I have two options, please suggest the most effective

- Option1: I can fetch all the five one by one and send via context to template and then show the each via html tabs
- Option2: Have separate page for each model and fetch when ever user goes to that page, like if user goes to page1 then i fetch data from model1 and so on

Which is good and effective? Like querying only needed or just query all and show up in a html tabs?

Comment: Can you explain why five ?

Comment: I just need to show profile details of user, and the user have 5 models like education, qualification etc !

Comment: Why not you are thinking of making one model instead of 5? You don't have  to query five times your  You have to query five times in both the case to your database. If you'll use  one model then there will be no space for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django debug toolbar to analyze the cost of your queries.

Also, if the models has a lot of rows and you are rendering it by sending via context in a template then it might be quite slow . Instead you might want to populate asynchronously.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: You mean asynchronously ?

Comment: yes ! right, how to do that asynchronously